# Extending Help Pages for ASP.NET Web API to support versioning

Tags: c#, versioning, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I am just wonder if there is any package or extension to Web API help pages to support versioning other than SDammann package.

I want to have something like this

```
    [MinVersion("1")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
     return "value";
    }
```

Then Api Help pages shows what is the minimum supported version.